# Permission Denial: opening provider MediaDocumentsProvider in API 21

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on APP where I give option to record or select already stored videos. I'm able to perform these operations without any issue. But when I close the activity and open it again, my activity isn't able to access the URIs again.

I get the exception:
D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource SecurityException happend :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{2e396c8 6917:com.rahul.android.casteeng/u0a145} (pid=6917, uid=10145) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3654)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2966)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1495)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1115)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:970)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:897)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1108)
at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:376)
at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:73)
at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:657)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:682)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:200)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:921)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2214)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6748)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I have already configured permission in AndroidMenifest.xml as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you compiling against API 23? if yes then you need runtime permission

Comment: It say's you require "android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" add that also..

Comment: check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178041/getting-permission-denial-exception

Comment: you need to ask permission to user manually .. 
for example see.. : https://androidexampleblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/androids-runtime-permission-example/

Comment: @SohailZahid. I'm compiling against API 21.

Comment: @sunilsunny. It has MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permissions also in menifest.

Comment: @UttamPanchasara.. I'll check if it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried adding run time permissions also but nothing worked for me. I updated my Samsung tab and seems like new updates solved this issue.