# SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for uri from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-securityexception

My app use camera to take a photo and use it for long term.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri resultUri = null;
resultUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
      new ContentValues());
imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, resultUri);
startActivityForResult(imageCaptureIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But when I call takePersistableUriPermission(), I will get SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found

I've read this
[Getting Permission Denial Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178041/getting-permission-denial-exception).
It works perfect to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.
How do I get a persistent permission from Camera?

Comment: You have the URI - why are you do need to persist access at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Wow. You're right. After reboot, uri from camera it can be accessed without persistent permission. But, why does it fail to uri from ACTION_GET_CONTENT if I don't call takePersistableUriPermission()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Access to `MediaStore` URIs are only controlled by the storage permissions (i.e., [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) so as long as you continue to hold the storage permission, you can access the Uris so in this case you don't need to persist permissions at all.

[URI based permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#uri), used in `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc. give special one time access to a URI via the [FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) being included with the returned `Intent`.

It is only document URIs (ones where [DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#isDocumentUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) returns true) that allow you to [persist permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions) to give more permanent access to a Uri.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. That helps a lot.

Comment: Not exactly. If you ask a user to choose a file using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` - the URI you receive will successfully pass `DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri()` but will fail if you try to save permission calling `takePersistableUriPermission()`  with exception `SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for //UID 10829 and Uri content://...` ;  You should open file chooser with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.