# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.Media

Tags: android, android-permissions, securityexception, android-securityexception

I am getting-

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{f1d408f 5594:firebasejobscheduler.test.com.firbasejobschedulerdemo/u0a1227} (pid=5594, uid=11227) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

at

```
 bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837358/android-kitkat-securityexception-when-trying-to-read-from-mediastore) post but not able to resolve it.How can i resolve this?

Comment: see this link,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178041/getting-permission-denial-exception

Comment: What is your testing device's OS Version?

Comment: Marshmallow and lollipop for two different devices

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran I have seen that and tried Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT .. but the crash is at "bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);"

Comment: crashed in which device?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178041/getting-permission-denial-exception

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran Marshmallow and lollipop

Comment: add this,  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);

Comment: or ur uri change to input stream, InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] inputData = getBytes(is);
is.close();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(inputData, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran I need to resize the images before converting to base64

Answer (score 2):

You must check for RunTimePermissions in Marshmallow.
check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/) .
check it for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: believe me its not working, securityException comes only when your application is not allowing some permission... your exception asking for **android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS** permission.. try for this permission too..

Comment: If you want to check your app anyway, then in your android device go to setting-> application->_yourapp_->permissions-> allow all the permissions required, **but its not recommended**, you should provide UI for allowing permission from application..
here you can see what permissions are required

Comment: i have added permission in both manifest and at runtime..i already checked that..i am using  `bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);` inside service and after i rebbot device if my service starts i get this crash

Comment: are you saving the permission status in sharedPreferences ?
It may happen if you dont save permission status.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void chooseImage() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("image/*");
    //i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    //ActivityResultLauncher for opening the gallery
    getImageFromGallery.launch(i);

}
```

That chooseImage() is a function to open the gallery. If you have checked that you have the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE already requested and accepted by the user, try changing or commenting i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) to i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).