# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: on fetching bitmap from uri inside service

Tags: android, permissions, securityexception, android-securityexception

I am getting-

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from
>   ProcessRecord{..} requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

at

```
 bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

I am using `bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);` inside a service.**I normally does NOT get this exception but if i reboot my device and then service gets called i get this exception**.I have specified android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS in manifest as well as at runtime and i have checked [Getting Permission Denial Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178041/getting-permission-denial-exception) answer too.

Comment: Where is `uri` coming from? When and where did you get that `Uri`? How is your service getting that `Uri`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I opened gallery from my activity and uri is coming from the selected image by user.Then i am using service to post that image to server when network connection is there using job scheduler.So if that service gets called after rebooting device i get this crash

Comment: @CommonsWare Suppose user selected image from gallery and network connection was not there..i scheduled that service using job scheduler.Then if i reboot my device i get this crash..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42078089/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lott !! It worked with takePersistableUriPermissions()