# Android "permission Denial", when receiving shared file

Tags: android, file, xamarin, permissions

So i am writing an app, that can receive files via the share menu from other apps. I have a `ShareActivity`, which has the intent filter for receiving files.

Once file is received `ShareActivity` is started and in that activity user must choose a folder in which the received file will be uploaded. When the user has chosen the folder, a service is started, which uploads the file.

The problem is that, the received file URI (from Google Photos) is passed to the `UploadService`and `Finish()` is called for `ShareActivity` and when the `ShareActivity` is finished, an exception is thrown:

```
[Xamarin.Insights] Warning: Unhandled exception: Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{cf1e0da 8268:lv.new_failiem/u0a247} (pid=8268, uid=10247) that is not exported from uid 10124
[Xamarin.Insights]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at Android.Content.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream (Android.Net.Uri uri) [0x00044] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Content.ContentResolver.cs:926 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at lv.failiem.android.UploadService+<UploadFiles>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0031a] in /Projects/Android/UploadService.cs:116
```

By doing some research, I found out that content providers issue a permission for that specific file only for the time, when the receiving activity is alive. When that activity is closed, permission is discarded and this exception is thrown. Indeed, if i don't call `Finish()` on my `ShareActivity`, everything works fine (but i need the upload to happen in background).

Is there a way to pass that permission to my service? I wan't the upload to happen in the background independent from any activity.

I read these StackOveflow posts:
[Using data from context providers or requesting Google Photos read permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572261/using-data-from-context-providers-or-requesting-google-photos-read-permission)

[java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.content.GooglePhotosImageProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082708/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-andr)

[Permission denial: opening provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368867/permission-denial-opening-provider)

One answer cought my eye (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909105/5884133), which says to

> use the temporary file path

Any ideas on how to solve this? How to get the temporary file path?

**Edit:**
When user has selected the folder in `ShareActivity`, this method gets called:

```
void AddUploadFiles(Folder folder) {
    switch (Intent.Action) {

    //For receiving one file
    case Intent.ActionSend:
        var result = Intent.GetParcelableExtra (Intent.ExtraStream);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (result.ToString());
        UploadService.AddFile (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (result.ToString ()), folder);
        StartService (new Intent(this, typeof(UploadService)));
        break;

    //For receiving multiple files
    case Intent.ActionSendMultiple:
        var imageUris = Intent.GetParcelableArrayListExtra (Intent.ExtraStream);
        foreach (var item in imageUris)
            UploadService.AddFile (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (item.ToString ()), folder);
        StartService (new Intent(this, typeof(UploadService)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Then the files get enqueued in the `UploadService` and are uploaded one by one.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - I can pass the issued permission to the `UploadService` like this:

```
var result = Intent.GetParcelableExtra (Intent.ExtraStream);
UploadService.AddFile (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (result.ToString ()), parentFolder);
var i = new Intent (this, typeof(UploadService));
i.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission); //Pass permission from content provider
i.SetData (Android.Net.Uri.Parse (result.ToString ()));
StartService (i);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Intents