# Playing audio from uri

Tags: android, audio, uri, media

I am getting `java.lang.SecurityException` when i try to play audio file.
I trying make simple app that selects audio from the phones memory and save it using `sqlit`e and list those selected before.

In the app,  first time plays audio file without any error. But after i restarted the app it does not play instead returns `SecurityException.` 
I am using this code below to pick audio file

```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), REQUEST_CODE);

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && data != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DATA " + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Prompting alertdialog for name of the audio file           
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter name for audio");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            builder.setView(input);
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   sql.addToHistory(new soundDB.Effects(null,data.getData().toString(),input.getText().toString()));
               new loadEffects().execute();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

and i am using those permissions at the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED" />
```

---

```
06-25 11:45:21.902 17298-17372/? I/DefaultRequestDirector: I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: Write error: ssl=0x8d334c00: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
06-25 11:46:03.204 7086-7086/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 893.003ms (threads: 4) arena alloc=3KB (3288B) java alloc=2MB (2752008B) native alloc=3MB (3826768B) free=2MB (2464688B)
06-25 11:46:12.890 7234-7234/? W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/545: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{d912193 7234:[package name]/u0a116} (pid=7234, uid=10116) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
06-25 11:46:12.938 7234-7234/? D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
```

Comment: your android OS Version is 6.0? or API 23?

Comment: i tried it on 5.1.1 emulator and android N beta device

Comment: you have get runtime permission for android 6.0 to onward.

Comment: i gave the permission from settings>apps manually

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14369137/1741586

Comment: thanks for the help but it didn't solve my problem and i tried other solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content this one worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But after i restarted the app it does not play instead returns SecurityException.

You only have rights to the content identified by a `Uri`, by default, for the lifetime of your process. Think of it as a URL tied to a user session in a Web app; once that session times out, the URL is no longer usable.

On API Level 19+, you can *try* [using `takePersistableUriPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to get more durable access to the content. However, that is more for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` than `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and so it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve it. When getting audio file uri, I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT, and add this line to onActivityResult.

It will play even after device reboot. The complete code snippet

```java
this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(currentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

```java
public void getAudioFileUri(View v) {

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
  intent.setType("audio/*");
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
  try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose audio file"), 1);
  } catch (Exception ex) {

  }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
  Uri currentUri = null;
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
      if (resultData != null) {
        currentUri = resultData.getData();
        this.musicUri = currentUri.toString();
        this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(currentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
    }
  }
}
```