# Save image to storage when app destroyed. Uri couldn't able to convert in Bitmap

Tags: android

I'm trying to save the image to the storage by using a work manager. I'm doing this by destroying the application. It's working fine when an application is on the foreground & in the background. But the issue is when application is destroyed. The Uri couldn't able to convert in the bitmap. Permission also is given (accessed). The URI is directly fetched from the gallery. It works absolutely fine if I don't destroy my application. I didn't use a provider in the manifest.

My code image address:
[image: My code image address]

My Logcat image address:
[image: My Logcat image address]

Image Picking code from the gallery:-

[Image Picking code from gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dstb6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denial: opening provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368867/permission-denial-opening-provider)

Comment: Are you picking image from storage and writing it to somewhere else in storage? From where you are getting uri?

Comment: @Amit Tiwary yes I'm picking the image from storage. There I get URI. Passing that URI to the worker.

Comment: Can you show me your code, how you are picking image?

Comment: @AmitTiwary code has been updated. Please check.

Comment: This is not image picking code. This is code after picking image.