# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to store image in firebase storage and here is what i get in logcat so please can any one explain what this log means:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{6c7b60d 25180:com.genius.fiberservice/u0a453} (pid=25180, uid=10453) that is not exported from UID 10098
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2360)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2285)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5933)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:7001)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2954)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2509)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1994)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1825)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1658)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1605)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:124)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241)
    at com.example.fiberservice.AddMapActivity.addNewMap(AddMapActivity.java:102)
    at com.example.fiberservice.AddMapActivity.access$000(AddMapActivity.java:29)
    at com.example.fiberservice.AddMapActivity$2.onClick(AddMapActivity.java:62)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7559)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1120)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7536)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28690)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7889)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368867/permission-denial-opening-provider

Comment: sorry but this not working!